# What does "Won't you take the time you were given" mean in the lyrics of "My Little Ruin"

Tags: lyrics

I need your kind help understanding the line "Won't you take the time you were given" used in a song by Glen Hansard called *My Little Ruin* - full lyrics available [here](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tjlbk5gnyfy5gy7fshx2bbvrf3y?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics).

> Come on, my little ruin
>   Won't you build yourself back up again
>   Won't you take the time you were given
>   You promised it to yourself
>   You could stand among the best of them
>   If you could hold your own
>   But no one's gonna do it for you now
>   But you and you alone

Comment: You don't want a translation. Translation means it's being changed from one language to another. You want to understand it, you want an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a belief that each person is given a certain amount of time to live

> the time we are given *(on this earth)*

the singer is saying that his friend should use *all* the time they were given to pick themselves back up again, and not end it prematurely.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, you have been very helpful.

Comment: @Peter: I agree with the meaning of 'time we are given', but I don't see anything that would imply that the person referred to in the song is going to '*end it prematurely*'...

Comment: It is not explicitly said, but given the amount of depression that's being described it's a possibility, otherwise why else would the singer care how much time is left?

Answer (score 0):

The writer of the song, Glen Hansard, has mentioned in multiple interviews, that the song "My Little Ruin" is written about a good friend of his, who, not matter what happens, keeps screwing up his life. Prior to playing the song [in this video](http://billions.com/news/news/video-glen-hansard-my-little-ruin/), he states that the song is about

> a friend who is a deeply, deeply gifted, talented human being, but
>   insists completely on f**king up every time things go right. This is
>   someone who steals defeat from the jaws of victory.

In the song, he is telling his friend to pay no heed to others, but to pick himself up, pull himself together and **use his time on earth wisely**, because no-one else is going to do it for him.

Another interview about the song can be found [here.](https://youtu.be/1zEiz3z6470?t=601)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your exhaustive answer. However, I was asking about that one particular phrase :-)